# Display Only the List of a YouTube Playlist Page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

If I have a playlist url, say "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRU-B1PBK4Buu_yoMI8V-eTel9O3gVMpB" and I put it in an iframe with:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUK376qNDlNZZDNHsnaWuTeg" width ="1920" height="1080"></iframe>
```

I get a blank iFrame, so how do I fix that? Also, I only want to display the "pl-video-list" div, not the rest of the web page. The other responses on stackoverflow were all website specific, or didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option extract playlist using JQuery

```
              <script>
    var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/UUK376qNDlNZZDNHsnaWuTeg?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    $.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
        var list_data="";
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var url = videoURL + videoID;
            list_data += '<a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><br><br>'+ feedTitle+'</a>';
        });
        $(list_data).appendTo(".playlist");
    });
            </script>

<ul class="playlist"></ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jamie8763/g5unx78b/

Comment: Displays blank page when I try, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> may need this if not already got

Comment: Chrome gives me the error:
GET https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/B2A4E1367126848D?v=2&alt=json&callback=jQuery16409446427025832236_1416784049442&_=1416784049446  jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4f.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4f.extend.getJSON jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function)

Comment: Got it to work, I accidentally put the <ul> outside the <html> tag.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer your were looking for but `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLRU-B1PBK4Buu_yoMI8V-eTel9O3gVMpB" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` allows you to view the first video in the playlist with a dropdown to view the rest of the playlist.

As for your blank iframe, I am getting the following error when I try it.

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRU-B1PBK4Buu_yoMI8V-eTel9O3gVMpB'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to scecify a certain div to display in an iframe. It's either all or nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I just need the list in the URL, thanks though!

Comment: Alright, I will try looking a little further into this and update my answer if I find anything.